# R: How to remove values from a table that appear in another table?

Tags: r, rsqlite

I have data that looks like this:

```
> head(dbGetQuery(mydb, 'SELECT * FROM geneExpDiffData WHERE significant = "yes"'))
      gene_id sample_1 sample_2 status value_1 value_2 log2_fold_change test_stat p_value   q_value significant
1 XLOC_000219       M4       M3     OK 3.85465 0.00000             -Inf        NA   5e-05 0.0075951         yes
2 XLOC_004272       M4       M3     OK 2.06687 0.00000             -Inf        NA   5e-05 0.0075951         yes
3 XLOC_004991       M4       M3     OK 3.29904 0.00000             -Inf        NA   5e-05 0.0075951         yes
4 XLOC_007234       M4       M3     OK 1.28027 0.00000             -Inf        NA   5e-05 0.0075951         yes
5 XLOC_000664       M4       F4     OK 1.46853 0.00000             -Inf        NA   5e-05 0.0075951         yes
6 XLOC_001809       M4       F4     OK 0.00000 1.91743              Inf        NA   5e-05 0.0075951         yes
```

I've produced two subsets with RSQLite:

```
M4M3 <- dbGetQuery(mydb, 'SELECT * FROM geneExpDiffData WHERE significant = "yes" AND sample_1 = "M4" AND sample_2 = "M3"')

M4F4 <- dbGetQuery(mydb, 'SELECT * FROM geneExpDiffData WHERE significant = "yes" AND sample_1 = "M4" AND sample_2 = "F4"')
```

I'd like to remove all values from M4M3 that have a matching gene_id in M4F4.  It's not important that I use RSQLite to filter the data set, it could be a pure R solution, but I'm not sure how to compare tables and remove rows from one based on another.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking when you refer to M4M3 and M4F4. Are you talking about the sample_1 and sample_2 values simultaneously? I.E. select values where (sample_1 = 'M4' AND sample_2 = 'M3') and gene_id = 'M4F4' ? I'm not following from the sample dataset you provided.

Comment: `M4M3.new <- M4M3[!(M4M3$gene_id %in% M4F4$gene_id),]` ?

Comment: If you look at the data table structure I want all rows where sample_1 = M4, sample_2 = M3 which do not have a matching gene_id in the comparison sample_1 = M4 and sample_2 = F4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bunch of ways to do this.

Base R subset solution (as noted by Balter above):

```
M4M3.new <- M4M3[!(M4M3$gene_id %in% M4F4$gene_id),]
```

Base R set union solution:

```
M4M3.new <- setdiff(M4M3, M4F4)
```

Dplyr solution

```
M4M3.new <- dplyr::anti_join(M4M3, 
                             M4F4, 
                             by = c("gene_id" = "gene_id"))
```

Edit: All appeared to work tested on the following dataset:

```
tst1 <- data.frame(gene_id = seq(1:10), 
                   sample_1 = rep("M4", 10), 
                   sample_2 = c(rep("M3", 6), rep("F4", 4)), 
                   other_values = sample(1:10, 10, replace = T),
                   other_values2 = rep("OK", 10))

M4M3 <- tst1[tst1$sample_1 == "M4" & tst1$sample_2  == "M3",]
M4F4 <- tst1[tst1$sample_1 == "M4" & tst1$sample_2  == "F4",]
```

Comment: For your `anti_join` solution, you could just set `by = "gene_id"`

Comment: you are right DMC. I was being as explicit as I could, but it's really not necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the join to run on the database, you could also connect via dbplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
src <- dbplyr::src_dbi(db)
geneExpDiffData <- tbl(src, "geneExpDiffData")

M4M3 <- geneExpDiffData %>%
  filter(significant == "yes" & sample_1 == "M4" & sample_2 == "M3")

M4F3 <- geneExpDiffData %>%
  filter(significant == "yes" & sample_1 == "M4" & sample_2 == "F4")

anti_join(M4M3, M4F3)
```

This has the advantage that you can use identical syntax for most applications, no matter if your data is in the database or in a local data frame. In fact `M4M3` and `M4F3` are just query objects, and the query 
will be run only when requested (e.g., if you display the data or run the join). Convert to a data frame via `collect()`:

```
result_df <- anti_join(M4M3, M4F3) %>% collect()
```

Learn more in the [introduction](http://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dbplyr.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could do that directly in one SQL statement like this:

```
M4M3 <- dbGetQuery(mydb, '
SELECT * 
FROM geneExpDiffData 
WHERE significant = "yes" 
AND sample_1 = "M4" 
AND sample_2 = "M3"
AND gene_id not in (SELECT gene_id 
                    FROM geneExpDiffData 
                    WHERE significant = "yes" 
                    AND sample_1 = "M4" 
                    AND sample_2 = "F4")
')
```

The code in the inner brackets returns a table of all `gene_id` that are in M4F4.
So we want all `gene_id` that are in the first table but not in the second.